# facing issue in jquery autocomplete with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am facing a problem in Jquery Autocomplete with Codeigniter.When I am using autocomplete data is coming but it is not visible.

View

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#suggest_product').autocomplete({
        source: '<?php echo site_url("cart/suggest_products"); ?>',
        select: function (event, ui) {
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            alert("auto");
            console.log(resp);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Oops, that didn't work. Please try again.");
        }
    });
    $.fn.extend({
        propAttr: $.fn.prop || $.fn.attr
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
function suggest_products(){
        print_r($this->Product_model->suggest_products($_REQUEST['term']));
    }
```

Model

```
function suggest_products($term){
        $data   = array();
        $term   = strtolower( addslashes( trim( urldecode($term) ) ) );
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->like('name',$term);
        $this->db->or_like('sku', $term);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $temp   =   $this->db->get('products')->result_array();
        $data   = json_encode($temp);
        return $data;
    }
```

Data is coming when seeing in firebug.Also ul , li are becoming but `<li><a></a></li>` is blank.

Please help

Comment: What does `$data` (or the output you see in console) look like.

Comment: [{"name":"BLOCKS GREY BIG PILLOW"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI autocomplete the data to be in one of the following formats:

- An array of strings
- An array of objects, each object needs to have `label` and/or `value` property

So this:

```
[{"name":"BLOCKS GREY BIG PILLOW"}]
```

Should be change to one of the following in your server side code:

```
["BLOCKS GREY BIG PILLOW"]
[{"label":"BLOCKS GREY BIG PILLOW"}]
```

Probably the easiest fix is to change this line:

```
$this->db->select('name AS `label`', FALSE);
```